# Which link function and error structure for standardized response variable consisting of proportion & count data in a mixed effect model

Tags: r, glm, mixed-models

This is my first question asked so apologies if my question is not asked according to the proper guidelines but I will be as detailed as possible.

I want to examine intersexual variation in fitness between different inbred lines using Drosophila. I have assayed fitness for 10 individuals from both sexes from each line (n=33 isolines). Female fitness was fecundity i.e. number of offspring a single female produced and male fitness as the proportion of offspring sired by a focal male in competition with a competitor male (competitive ability). As both measures are on different scales (i.e. counts & proportions) I Z transformed data prior to analysis.

A sample of my data looks like this (I have a few NAs due to deaths)

```
line    sex fitness
3a  male    -0.086616292
3a  male    1.077458823
3a  male    -1.011906768
3a  male    1.077458823
3a  male    -0.126015757
3a  male    1.077458823
3a  male    -1.429779886
3a  male    NA
3a  male    NA
3a  male    -0.150576463
4a  male    0.498865275
4a  male    -0.651671321
4a  male    0.472263273
4a  male    -0.426884402
4a  male    0.165735656
4a  male    -1.429779886
4a  male    -1.429779886
4a  male    -1.429779886
```

I am interested in the main effect of line and the sex*line interaction. I have treated sex as a fixed effect and line and the line*sex interaction as random effects

This is first time fitting a model like this so I suspect I have some errors, see below.

My questions are as follows

(1) Do I need to specify a specific link function and error structure besides the default Gaussian and identity? As my response variable is a mix of count and proportion data which has been Z transformed to be on the same scale and in a single column (i.e. fitness) it is neither Poisson or Binomial. Furthermore after transforming (i.e. standardizing) my fitness measures my response variable is not normal  So is there some error structure to account for this ?

(2) Regarding my model testing procedure I cannot find a straight forward answer in help forums or books to account for testing the interaction between a fixed and random effect (sex*line) which I am interested in. I am not entirely confident with procedure below my if someone could provide some tips regarding this i'd really appreciate it.

I've included the output for when I used anova to compare models with and without the effects I was testing for the significance for below the code for each model.

```
model1<-lmer(fitness~sex+(1|line)+(1|sex:line),data=BL1InxNoOutLiars,REML=FALSE) #FULL MODEL
    summary(model1)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: fitness ~ sex + (1 | line) + (1 | sex:line) 
   Data: BL1InxNoOutLiars 

REML criterion at convergence: 1682.278 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 sex:line (Intercept) 0.03565  0.1888  
 line     (Intercept) 0.08432  0.2904  
 Residual             0.78479  0.8859  
Number of obs: 626, groups: sex:line, 66; line, 33

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) -0.05413    0.07800  -0.694
sexmale      0.05028    0.08491   0.592

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr)
sexmale -0.533


    model<-lmer(fitness~(1|line)+(1|sex:line),data=BL1InxNoOutLiars,REML=FALSE)
    anova(model1,model2) #test significance of sex, p=0.5365

OUTPUT
model2: fitness ~ (1 | line) + (1 | sex:line)
model1: fitness ~ sex + (1 | line) + (1 | sex:line)
          Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
model2   4 1683.9 1701.7 -837.96   1675.9                         
model1  5 1685.5 1707.8 -837.78   1675.5 0.3644      1     0.5461

    model3<-lmer(fitness~(1|sex:line),data=BL1InxNoOutLiars,REML=FALSE)
    model4<-update(model1.1,~.-sex,REML=TRUE)#remove sex from full model as it is non-significant
    anova(model4,model3)#test significant of line, p=0.012

OUTPUT
Models:
model3: fitness ~ (1 | sex:line)
model4: fitness ~ (1 | line) + (1 | sex:line)
         Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)  
model3  3 1688.0 1701.3 -841.00   1682.0                          
model4  4 1683.9 1701.7 -837.96   1675.9 6.074      1    0.01372 *


    model5<-lmer(fitness~(1|line),data=BL1InxNoOutLiars,REML=FALSE)
    anova(model4,model5)###LINE X SEX INTERACTION IS NS P=0.1558

OUTPUT
model5: fitness ~ (1 | line)
model4: fitness ~ (1 | line) + (1 | sex:line)
          Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
model5  3 1683.9 1697.2 -838.97   1677.9                         
model4   4 1683.9 1701.7 -837.96   1675.9 2.0143      1     0.1558
```

Apologies if I have not been clear or have asked my questions in the incorrect fashion any guidance on this is also appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Residuals (not the raw response) are assumed to be normally distributed; with `lmer` the random effects are also assumed to be normally distributed: `qqnorm(resid(model))` and `qqnorm(ranef(model)[[1]][,1])` are a starting point. If you wish to include random coefficients for sex across lines (ie. an 'interaction' between sex and line) and random intercepts for each line, use the syntax `(1 + sex|line)` for the random effect.

Comment: to expand slightly; if you are interested in some sort of hypothesis test regarding the random effect (the random coefficients of `sex|line`), consider a parametric bootstrap to generate a confidence interval. See function `bootMer` in `lme4`

Comment: @NatePope Thanks a bunch for your input the qqnorm(resid(model))  plot was very helpful